# Fiddler not showing requests for .net web application while debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I am debugging a .Net Web api and want to test various verbs (Get, Post, Put, Delete) using fiddler, but fiddler is not showing the requests when I run the and see it in chrome.
I got some info on [this page](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/MonitorLocalTraffic) page, but not able to understand how to use it.
If somebody knows, please let me know how to configure it.

[image]

Comment: Are you using Google chrome to test your web API? Unless you use some sort of plugin/extension I don't you'll be able to reproduce POST, PUT and DELETE requests. Maybe that is your problem. Try using something like Postman.

Comment: @IPValverde, yes, I'm using google chrome. You said that I won't be able to reproduce POST, PUT, DELETE requests, but what about GET request. is that also not captured !

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your fiddler and what it is showing exactly?

Comment: I have added the picture, I updated the fiddler before using it, when I opened it first time l. And this "reenable capturing" message in yellow background appears again and again after sometime. All the requests to "localhost:54016" and "localhost:55443" are made using fiddler, they are not the captured one.

Comment: I got the reason for that yellow background message, it appears when I make some changes in the code and restarts the application.